# How to set bottom margin to FAB in Anko DSL layout?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I use Anko DSL layout in my kotlin activity. I can not set bottom margin to FAB. Right margin work.

[image]

In my activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    (application as SamfantozziApp).dgaeacomponent().inject(this)

    InvoiceListKtActivityUI(_rxBus).setContentView(this)

}
```

My Anko DSL layout InvoiceListKtActivityUI.kt

```
class InvoiceListKtActivityUI (val _rxBus: RxBus): AnkoComponent<InvoiceListKtActivity>{

override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<InvoiceListKtActivity>): View = with(ui){

    return relativeLayout{
        padding = dip(5)
        lparams {
            width = matchParent
            height = wrapContent
            margin = 5
        }

        verticalLayout{

            tabLayout{
                lparams {
                width = matchParent
                height = wrapContent
                }
                id = R.id.tabs

            }

            viewPager{
                lparams {
                width = matchParent
                height = matchParent
                }
                id = R.id.container

            }

        }

        floatingActionButton{
            lparams {
                width = wrapContent
                height = wrapContent
                rightMargin = 40   //works
                bottomMargin = 40  //does not work
                alignParentBottom()
                alignParentRight()
            }
            imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_input_add
            id = R.id.fabinvoice
            onClick{
                _rxBus.send(InvoiceListFragment.ClickFobEvent())
            }

        }

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: you can try `margin = dip(40)`, it worked for me

Comment: to @Hawkings I am sorry it does not work. It is the same result. Can you send me link to your ankocomponent, please ?

Comment: I use it like this: `coordinatorLayout { verticalLayout { /* the rest of the content goes here */ } floatingActionButton().lparams { margin = dip(40) } }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not setting the lparams correctly. The proper form is:

```
floatingActionButton {
    imageResource = android.R.drawable.ic_input_add
}.lparams{
    rightMargin = dip(16)
    bottomMargin = dip(16)
    alignParentBottom()
    alignParentRight()
}
```